# after installing monit when i do monit status myproc i get "error connecting to the monit daemon"

Tags: linux, monit

after installing monit when i do monit status myproc i get "error connecting to the monit daemon"

I read somewhere that

> The status command won't work in the
>   case that monit is running indaemon
>   mode without its http support - the
>   command 'monit status' in such case
>   tries to get the status from the
>   daemon via http/tcp. To start the http
>   interface you need to add the 'set
>   httpd ...' statement to
>   theconfiguration.

is that still correct? that post was from 2005

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was struggling to setup monit on my ubuntu server and here are a few things to check:

- Make sure that you set startup=1 in /etc/default/monit
- Make sure to un-comment the httpd parameters in /etc/monit/monitrc

One last "gotcha" in /etc/monit/monitrc:

```
set daemon  120           # check services at 2-minute intervals
#  with start delay 240  # optional: delay the first check by 4-minutes (by
#                           # default Monit check immediately after Monit start)
```

I had the "with start delay 240" line un-commented at first.  It appears that the httpd server will not start immediately if you use this option.  It took me awhile to realize why monit was running but the httpd server was not.

Comment: Note - the http parameters must be uncommented even to view a summary from the command line using i.e. ``sudo monit summary``

Comment: Yeah, but the annoying part is that is says `Starting Monit 5.9 daemon with http interface at` at `var/log/monit.log` right after monit is started, this is misleading.

Answer (score 12):

```
 set httpd port 2812 and
  use address 0.0.0.0
  allow 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
  allow admin:monit
```

I think this is better,it will add a web page to see the monit result,and the user name and password is admin and monit.

Answer (score 3):

In order to make this work, you have to set the monit httpd process to allow connections from localhost.

In your config file, you should uncomment the line that says `allow localhost` and restart monit.

Answer (score 2):

I'v added this lines my conf file

```
set httpd port 2812 and
use address localhost
allow localhost
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have enabled the HTTP daemon and added allow localhost. There's a write up on how to correctly configure monit to avoid this error [here](http://www.idimmu.net/2013/03/28/monit-error-connecting-to-the-monit-daemon/).

Answer (score 1):

I got:
Cannot create socket to [localhost]:2812 -- Connection refused

until I rebooted the VM.. as in windows: reboot is good after installing monit

Comment: There's got to be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I got: Cannot create socket to [localhost]:2812 -- Connection refused

On ubuntu 20.04... until I udated the monitrc file to set the httpd settings and then ran:

sudo systemctl restart monit.service

This last part was key.